# Terminal - how to display 'shades' unicode characters properly?

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode

In Ubuntu 14.04, in the terminal I want to display the three Unicode characters:

U+2591 ░ Light shade

U+2592 ▒ Medium shade

U+2593 ▓ Dark shade

When I echo these characters in the terminal, I get the following, regardless which font I'm using.:

[image: unicode shade characters]

How to make them look as above (from Wikipedia)?

EDIT:

This screenshot shows exactly what I mean:

[image: screenshot 2]

On the left is a bit of Geany with the character I want to display. On the right the same character as it appears in the terminal. Clearly they are different. Perhaps I'm being a bit thick here... I want the character to be displayed as in Geany, ie. as a small chessboard.

Comment: Those look like dark, medium and light to me. Change the terminal background colour, if you don't like it.

Comment: The ones in my terminal are different to those in wikipedia. Mine seem to be solid, whereas wikipedia ones, particularly 'Light shade', are see-through.

Comment: O.o They are see-through in your case. You can see the background colour behind the blocks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329997/how-could-i-guarantee-a-terminal-has-unicode-wide-character-support-with-ncurses

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt

Comment: muru, please take a look at the EDIT in my original question. Sorry if I'm being stupid here and can't see the obvious. :)

Comment: @Alichino You want the dots? Hmm. What happens in other terminal emulators, like XFCE Terminal or Terminator?

Comment: I've just tried Terminator, and it displays as I want it! Why is gnome not doing the same? I could swear when I was playing with it a year ago everything was fine...

Comment: I have no idea why GNOME Terminal is different here. It, XFCE and Terminator all use [vte](https://github.com/GNOME/vte), so they should behave mostly the same. FWIW, newer versions of GNOME Terminal behave the same, and nothing in the changelogs for 14.04 indicate anything changed about this.

Comment: @muru "nothing in the changelogs for 14.04 indicate anything changed about this" – you can't seriously expect the changelog of an entire distribution to go into such minor details :)

Comment: @muru XFCE and Terminator use Gtk+ version 2, and in turn, a 5 year old, no longer maintained, and in  many aspects buggy and outdated VTE. GNOME Terminal uses the newest one which is way better in hundreds of aspects; alas not in this one for you.

Comment: @egmont no, I don't, but if OP had it working correctly last year, I figured something must have changed over that time to 14.04's GNOME Terminal

Answer (score 3):

The U+2500 .. U+25AF characters are drawn manually by VTE, not taken from the font. And, indeed, the three particular characters you've mentioned are drawn as single solid colors.

This is the same as the imaginary result of printing the pattern with the dots being infinitely small (and having an infinite amount of them to achieve the desired density), and applying antialiasing.

I *guess* the reason for this approach was that printing multiple of these characters next to each other with your preferred look doesn't look nice on the boundary of such cells at many font sizes.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, your answer explains the problem, that's for sure! However, is there a way to display the shades as I want? As you said - taken from the font?

Comment: You need to modify VTE's source code in order to do this.